# Mailcore2 iOS Test sample duplicating emails when loading more

Tags: ios, objective-c, mailcore2

I am using MailCore2 email library in my iOS app. I am following "iOS Test" sample mail core project. When I click on "Load 10 more" option at the bottom of email table view, emails are getting duplicated in the table "iOS Test" sample project. I want to integrate this and not getting how to fix this, I tried to comment out this line `[combinedMessages addObjectsFromArray:strongSelf.messages];` in loadLastNMessages function, but not helped.
 Could someone please advise me how to solve this duplicate email listing in this table view issue?

Screenshot where duplicating email date being displayed when loading more mails.

[image]

Comment: i just used it. it works just fine. are you sure you hadn't modify it? or that your data is actually not duplicated?

Comment: No, I haven't modified anything.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem.

Step to reproduce:

1-Load email message successfully (account A).

2-Send an email from "Account B" to "Account A".

3-Load more messages.
If I change `strongSelf.messages = nil` before I execute this code "`combinedMessages addObjectsFromArray:strongSelf.messages];"`. Not duplicate.
But It's not working if my account doesn't receive an new email.